# SEO & Multilingual:  would be this a good practise?

Tags: seo, php, language, best-practices, internationalization

I am currently making a bilingual website and I'd like to get nice SEO results of course.

**Here's my idea:**

The internal links would be composed of the "www" subdomain so that people can share links regardless of their language. Anyway, their language is determined by the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` PHP variable.

So, they would see http:// www.site.com/mydocument/123 in their adress bar and never see any links like "http:// fr.site.com/mydocument/123" or "http://en.site.com/mydocument/123"

The user can always switch the page's language thanks to links in the footer.
The switching language link would be : http:// fr.site.com/mydocument/123 , and clicking on it would change his language session and redirects the user to http:// www.site.com/mydocument/123

**In case of a crawling bot:**

I read that if the HTTP_USER_LANGUAGE variable was missing then it's a crawling bot.

So, in that case, we set the defaut language as English. Each page, as I mentionned earlier, has a link for another language:
On the page: **http:// www.site.com/document/1323**, the link **http:// fr.site.com/document/1323** can be seen by the bot and be crawled.

- What do you think about this practise ?
- Would I get good SEO results for each language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practices are often the simplest practices (particularly when there are many different systems involved) - maintaining session data for every visitor and redirecting behind the scenes isn't very simple.

**For SEO:** Search engines will *automatically* return results in the language which matches the user's language preferences and search terms, and users will have the same option to switch their language by navigating to a different subdomain without any redirects.

**For link sharing:** set up your redirect script at `www.site.com` and provide the language-based redirect links for anyone who wants to use them, but don't *force* anyone (or any search engine spiders) to use them.

Comment: So , you would recommend :  
1) to redirect people to the langage subdomain
french guy goes to http://fr.site.com 
2) if I visit a shared "www" link, I get redirected to http://fr.site.com because I speak french ?

Comment: Automatic redirection should be limited to requests against `www` (and you should include `Disallow: /` in the robots.txt file for the `www` subdomain) - all other subdomains should serve localized content as usual with links to other translations. See [Wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org/) as a model of interlinking.

Comment: I don't really understand. 
Could you give me an example, I'd really appreciate!

Comment: I am not aware of any good examples of the redirect scheme - it would only be effective for users who are sharing your links (search engines would not index the redirected URL's).